# How to use Lumen/Laravel custom service

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, arangodb

Im new to Lumen, I have managed to create and register the following ArangoDB service provider along with the service below and got it to work, but Im confused how I actually use them in another service or helper.

registered the provider in bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register(App\Providers\ArangoServiceProvider::class);
```

ArangoServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ArangoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('ArangoService', function ($app) {
        return new ArangoService($app);
    });
}
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

ArangoService.php

```
<?
namespace App\Services;

use ArangoDBClient\Collection as ArangoCollection;
use ArangoDBClient\CollectionHandler as ArangoCollectionHandler;
use ArangoDBClient\Connection as ArangoConnection;
use ArangoDBClient\ConnectionOptions as ArangoConnectionOptions;
use ArangoDBClient\DocumentHandler as ArangoDocumentHandler;
use ArangoDBClient\Document as ArangoDocument;
use ArangoDBClient\Exception as ArangoException;
use ArangoDBClient\Export as ArangoExport;
use ArangoDBClient\ConnectException as ArangoConnectException;
use ArangoDBClient\ClientException as ArangoClientException;
use ArangoDBClient\ServerException as ArangoServerException;
use ArangoDBClient\Statement as ArangoStatement;
use ArangoDBClient\UpdatePolicy as ArangoUpdatePolicy;



class ArangoService{
    public function __construct()    {

        $connectionOptions = [
            // database name
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_DATABASE => 'dbname',
            // server endpoint to connect to
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_ENDPOINT => 'tcp://123456789',
            // authorization type to use (currently supported: 'Basic')
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_AUTH_TYPE => 'Basic',
            // user for basic authorization
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_AUTH_USER => 'root',
            // password for basic authorization
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_AUTH_PASSWD => 'passwd',
            // connection persistence on server. can use either 'Close' (one-time connections) or 'Keep-Alive' (re-used connections)
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_CONNECTION => 'Keep-Alive',
            // connect timeout in seconds
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_TIMEOUT => 3,
            // whether or not to reconnect when a keep-alive connection has timed out on server
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_RECONNECT => true,
            // optionally create new collections when inserting documents
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_CREATE => true,
            // optionally create new collections when inserting documents
            ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_UPDATE_POLICY => ArangoUpdatePolicy::LAST,
        ];

        // turn on exception logging (logs to whatever PHP is configured)
        ArangoException::enableLogging();


        $connection = new ArangoConnection($connectionOptions);
        $collectionHandler = new ArangoCollectionHandler($connection);
        $handler = new ArangoDocumentHandler($connection);


    }
    public function main(){
        print "hello world!<br/>";
    }
}
```

This all above works, but how do I in a controller, call a service, lets call it "UsersService" that has functions like GetUser() , how does this "UsersService" use the **$connection**, **$collectionHandler** and **$handler** , that I have created in my ArangoDB service.

- route pointing to a controller (got that one)
- controller calling UsersService
- UsersService using the arango service and passing something back to the controller

grateful for any help!

Comment: Once you're register the `ServiceProvider`, you can simply call `$arangoService = app['ArangoService']` that will return the instance of `ArangoService` class

Comment: @Haridarshan thank you. but how would i, when i have the returned instance, "use/access" the collection handler?
$collectionHandler = new ArangoCollectionHandler($connection);

Comment: You can store `ArangoConnection`, `ArangoCollectionHandler`, `ArangoDocumentHandler` in class private members and via getter method you can retrieve them from `ArangoService` instance/object. e.g. `$collectionHandler = $arangoService->getCollectionHandler();`

Comment: i think i understand, thank you.